# Max character length on textarea using Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I am trying to limit the amount of characters a user inputs into a textarea field using Formtastic however cannot find any documentation on how to do this. Textarea in HTML5 supports maxlength

Here is my code:

$ <%= f.input :about_me, :as => :text %>

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= f.input :about_me, :as => :text, :input_html => { :maxlength => 10 } %>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= f.text_area :abc, :class => "form-control", id: "xyz", :maxlength => 200 %>
```